# Appium Inspector for android " ERROR: debug: executing:"

Tags: android, testing, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm using appium inspector on windows to generate test cases, but I can't make it work.

While trying to debug any apk on gui interface, the log show this error:

```
 Starting Node Server
 info: Starting Appium in pre-launch mode
 info: Pre-launching app
 ERROR: debug: Using fast reset? true
 info: Using local app from command line: C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\Notepad-1.4.0.7.apk
 ERROR: debug: executing: "C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\adt\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
 info: Creating new appium session 6a8176de-33c7-43ab-90b8-bd87c116f037
 info: Starting android appium
 info: Preparing device for session
 info: Checking whether app is actually present
 info: Checking whether adb is present
 info: [ADB] Using adb from C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\adt\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
 info: Trying to find a connected android device
 info: [ADB] Getting connected devices...
 info: [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
 ERROR: debug: executing: "C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\adt\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
 info: Setting device id to emulator-5554
 info: [ADB] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
 ERROR: debug: executing: "C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\adt\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
 info: Starting logcat capture
 info: Getting device API level
 ERROR: debug: executing: "C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\adt\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
 info: Device is at API Level 18
 ERROR: debug: executing: "C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\adt\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
 ERROR: debug: Current device language: en
 ERROR: debug: java -jar "C:\Users\leo\Downloads\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\helpers\strings_from_apk.jar" "C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\Notepad-1.4.0.7.apk" "C:\Windows\Temp\org.openintents.notepad.noteslist.NotesList" en
 info: No strings.xml for language 'en', getting default strings.xml
 ERROR: debug: java -jar "C:\Users\leo\Downloads\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\helpers\strings_from_apk.jar" "C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\Notepad-1.4.0.7.apk" "C:\Windows\Temp\org.openintents.notepad.noteslist.NotesList"
 ERROR: debug: executing: "C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\adt\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 push "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\org.openintents.notepad.noteslist.NotesList\\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
 info: Checking whether aapt is present
 ERROR: debug: Set app process to: slist.NotesList
 ERROR: debug: Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
 ERROR: debug: Checking app cert for C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\Notepad-1.4.0.7.apk: java -jar "C:\Users\leo\Downloads\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\helpers\verify.jar" "C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\Notepad-1.4.0.7.apk"
 ERROR: debug: App not signed with debug cert.
 ERROR: debug: Resigning apk with: java -jar "C:\Users\leo\Downloads\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\helpers\sign.jar" "C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\Notepad-1.4.0.7.apk" --override
 info: Zip-aligning C:\Users\leo\Documents\apps\Notepad-1.4.0.7.apk
 ERROR: debug: Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
 info: Checking whether zipalign is present
 info: Stopping logcat capture
 info: Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...

 ERROR: 
 Node Server Process Ended
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the inspector with "configuration Reset": "true"